# KornShell- Creating a fixed width text file

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I need to create a simple fixed width text file in KornShell (ksh).  My [current attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730183/korn-shell-printf-padding-a-string) using printf to pad the string isn't working out very well.  What's the shortest, cleanest way to create a fixed width string in ksh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KSH compresses several spaces into one when it parses certain inputs. So to achieve what you want, you must write the formatted string directly to a file without passing it through any variables. Use `printf` to format everything in one go and redirect to the file:

```
printf "%-10s%-5s%-20s\n" $str1 $str2 $str3 >> file
```

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in my answer to that question, you need to put quotes around your variables.

```
TEXT=`padSpaces "TEST" 10`
TEXT="${TEXT}A"
echo ${TEXT}
TEST A
echo "${TEXT}"
TEST          A
```